# Case statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case

I am not sure what to use in this scenario, but I think a Case statement is apt.

I do not know the syntax however. Can someone please guide me?

I have a variable called `@Action` which can have about 30 different values.

I want to do something like this

```
 CASE
 WHEN @Action = 'InsertTbl1' THEN 
  BEGIN
   -- Some Insert statements and one update statements
  END
 WHEN @Action = 'RecalculateCol3' THEN 
  BEGIN
   -- Some update statements
  END
 WHEN @Action = 'Closed' THEN 
  BEGIN
   -- Some delete statements and some update statements

  END
--- and so on.....
 ELSE 
  BEGIN
  END
 END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest a structure of `IF` and `ELSE IF` to mimic a switch.

```
IF @MyVar = 'Foo'
BEGIN
    --react to Foo        
END

ELSE IF @MyVar = 'Bar'
BEGIN
    --react to Bar       
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --default case.
END
```

Comment: +1, this is pretty much the only way for multiple inserts & updates in a block

Comment: in an if statement it goes through all the 30 ifs all the time - in a case statement, once a case is found, the rest is not checked.

Comment: is there something called Else IF so I can have a nested if statement instead of individual If statements....?

Comment: @Needs: suggest that the calling code should decide which of 30 stored procs to call, rather than having one proc with 30 different usages and SQL statements within! "One reason to change".

Comment: The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Else If.  For example:

```
declare @temp int
set @temp = 3

if @temp = 1
    print '1'
else if @temp > 1 and @temp < 3
    print '2'
else if @temp >= 3
    print '3'
```

I would still think about breaking it up into separate procedures as suggested by others